# Error While serializing arraylist. Getting NotSerializable Exception..Even after implementing Serializable

Tags: java

I'm trying to achieve the following...

1. I have an ArrayList of type class which stores class objects
2. each time it stores a new object I serialize it and wipe out the previous object.
3. I have methods like add search delete etc.
4. when I try to add I get then exception,

   Exception Caught: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.BufferedReader

code:

```
public static ArrayList<Library> bookData = new ArrayList<Library>();


public void addBook()
{
    objCount++;
    try{
        System.out.println("_________________Enter Book Details_________________");
        System.out.println(" Enter title of the Book    : ");
        this.setBookTitle();
        System.out.println(" Enter the Name of Author   : ");
        this.setBookAuthor();
        System.out.println(" Enter the Subject of Book  : ");
        this.setBookSubject();
        System.out.println(" Enter the Price of Book    : ");
        this.setBookPrice();
        System.out.println(" Enter Number of Copies     :");
        this.setNoOfCopies();

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("Database.ser");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.flush();
            oos.writeObject(bookData);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("IO Exception Caught: "+e);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
    }finally{
        try{
            File file = new File("Books_Index.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
            int count=getObjCount();
            fw.write("\nBook Index ["+count+"] Contains Book Named: ["+getBookTitle()+"]");
            fw.close();
            //saveData();

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception Caught: "+e);
        }
    }

}
```

Which, I googled and got the answer as you need to implement serializable interface.

I have already implemented it.

What could be the reason. I'm sending code by sharing my pastebin link

Link: https://pastebin.com/Q8F3iwex

Answer (score 0):

Classes that implement Serializable interface can be serialized. InputStreamReader and BufferedReader don't implement this interface.

Quick Solution is that:

```
  protected transient InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

  protected transient BufferedReader scan = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

it serializes objects in an object recursively when you serialize the object,Every object must be serializable.From the source code in jdk,object which is a `String`,`Array`,`Enum` or an implementation of `Serializable` can be serialized.

source code in `ObjectOutputStream`

```
        // remaining cases
        if (obj instanceof String) {
            writeString((String) obj, unshared);
        } else if (cl.isArray()) {
            writeArray(obj, desc, unshared);
        } else if (obj instanceof Enum) {
            writeEnum((Enum<?>) obj, desc, unshared);
        } else if (obj instanceof Serializable) {
            writeOrdinaryObject(obj, desc, unshared);
        } else {
            if (extendedDebugInfo) {
                throw new NotSerializableException(
                    cl.getName() + "\n" + debugInfoStack.toString());
            } else {
                throw new NotSerializableException(cl.getName());
            }
        }
```

In your `Library` class,there is a `BufferedReader` field,it can not be serialized.
you can try this

`transient BufferedReader scan = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`

Or implement your own serialization logic like this:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    //your own serialization logic
    .......
}
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    //your own deserialization logic
    ........
}
```